# Rails Query if Array contains other Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, where-clause

I have a Filter class that I am using to filter sublet listings. In my filter class I have a Listing method that returns all the listings that fit the criteria entered by the user in a form. Here is the filter class.

```
class Filter < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :air_conditioning, :available_rooms, :bathrooms, :furnished, :negotiable, :new, :parking, :maximum_price, :private_bathroom, :show, :term, :total_rooms, :utilities, :washer_dryer
  serialize :term

  def listings
    @listings ||=find_listings
  end

private

    def find_listings
    listings=Listing.order(:price)
    listings=listings.where("listings.price <= ?", maximum_price) if maximum_price.present?
    listings=listings.where(total_rooms: total_rooms) if total_rooms.present?
    listings=listings.where(available_rooms: available_rooms) if available_rooms.present?
    listings=listings.where(bathrooms: bathrooms) if bathrooms.present?
    listings=listings.where(term: term)
    listings=listings.where(furnished: furnished)
    listings=listings.where(negotiable: negotiable)
    listings=listings.where(utilities: utilities)
    listings=listings.where(air_conditioning: air_conditioning)
    listings=listings.where(parking: parking)
    listings=listings.where(washer_dryer: washer_dryer)
    listings=listings.where(private_bathroom: private_bathroom)
    listings
  end

 end
```

There problem is the line

```
listings=listings.where(term: term)
```

Term is saved as a string that can be serialized. Aka ['Summer', 'Fall] The user checks checkboxes to select which terms the sublet is available for. However, that where clause fails every time. How can I check if the elements chosen by the user are contained in the terms for a listing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you intended to do with term, but can you just make it a string type and then use something like this?

```
TERMS = %w(Spring Summer Fall Winter)
validates :term, :inclusion => { :in => TERMS }
```

EDIT: Also, did you intend to have Filter actually be a table in your database, or just a model with validations? If the latter, you may want to look into using ActiveModel: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/

Comment: You're right, it's not a query. What error do you get when you try to run the code you posted? What does the Listing schema look like? Since it's a serialized field for a Ruby object, you probably can't use it in a SQL query like that. But you could filter it after you get the results from the database, something like this:
    listings.find_all { |l| l.include? term }